# Extracting file using 7-Zip is taking too much time

Tags: command-line, batch-file, 7-zip

I am trying to extract a ZIP folder using 7-Zip from the command line:

```
7z x "%BackupFileDestination%" -o"%ExtractDestinationDir%"
```

It is taking too much time to do so. It is even hanging on a few files. Which switch is available that can make the extraction quick like the one for compression `-mx5`?

Answer (score 3):

The compression level switch allows to make a tradeoff between *time* and *compression* - compress the file quickly and end up with a potentially bigger file, or take your time and get a smaller file.

**There's no switch to make *extraction* faster** - why would anyone *not* use that switch?